# I can't place text and video in same grid in django with css

Tags: html, css, django, frontend, grid

I have application which includes 3 videos(eventually it will include more). I have created a model in models.py and passed courses to template with context in my view.
**I want my title to be in border below the video but it makes some weird pose.** [image: weird pose.]

I left some space under image for title.

**html**

```
<div class="next">
        {% for course in courses %}
            {{ course.title }}
            <video src="/media/{{ course.videofile }}" controls=controls type="video" class="video">{{ course.title }}</video>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**css**

```
.next{
    margin-top: 8em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: .1fr .1fr .1fr;
    gap: 1em;
}
.video{
    max-width: 15em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

If I place for loop in another div it works better but titles are above videos.

**html**

```
<div class="next">
        {% for course in courses %}
            <div class="div">
                {{ course.title }}
                <video src="/media/{{ course.videofile }}" controls=controls type="video" class="video">{{ course.title }}</video>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

(css is the same)

[image]

Comment: The text between the `<video>` and `</video>` tags will only be displayed in browsers that do not support the `<video>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If I place for loop in another div it works better but titles are above videos.*** - Update your **CSS** like this

```
.next{
    margin-top: 8em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: .1fr .1fr .1fr;
    gap: 1em;
}
.video{
    min-width: 15em;
    max-width: 15em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
.video *{
    width: 100%;
}
```

and **HTML** will look like this

```
<div class="next">
  {% for course in courses %}
     <div class="video">
            {{ course.title }}
            <video src="/media/{{ course.videofile }}" controls=controls type="video" >{{ course.title }}</video>
        </div>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

### Working example

```css
.next{
    margin-top: 8em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: .1fr .1fr .1fr;
    gap: 1em;
}
.video{
    min-width: 15em;
    max-width: 15em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
.video *{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="next">
  
  <div class="video">
   <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" controls=controls type="video"></video>
   Big Buck Bunny
  </div>
  
  <div class="video">
   <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" controls=controls type="video"></video>
   Big Buck Bunny
  </div>

</div>
```